# Função para incrementar o nome do ficheiro - python(opencv)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

eu tenho este código que me guarda um video cada vez que corro o programa com o nome video0.

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(video0.avi', fourcc, fps, (int(width), int(height)))
```

Queria agora cada vez que corresse o programa ele guardasse o video com outro nome.
1ª vez :video0
2ª vez :video1
3ª vez :video2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só precisas de fazer o seguinte:

```
import os

filename = 'video0.avi'
if os.path.exists(filename):
  tmp = filename.split('.avi')
  count = tmp[0].replace('video', '') or 0
  count = int(count) + 1
  new_filename = 'video{0}.avi'.format(count)
```

Basicamente, verificas se existe em disco, vais precisar do path para a localização do ficheiro, depois fazes um split pelo ponto e a entensão do ficheiro depois removes o nome base e incrementas o resultado, se não existir com o "or 0" adiciona um defalt.

O mesmo com função.

```
import os

def load_file(filename):
  if os.path.exists(filename):
    tmp = filename.split('.avi')
    count = tmp[0].replace('video', '') or 0
    count = int(count) + 1
    return 'video{0}.avi'.format(count)
  return filename

filename = 'video.avi'
print(load_file(filename))
```

Percorrendo toda a diretoria.

```
import os, re, os.path

def load_file(file):
  number = []
  onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('.', f))]  # load all dir files
  filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)                                 # load filename and extension from parameter file
  total_files = len(onlyfiles)                                                      # get total files in dir
  splitter = re.compile(r'\d+')                                                     # build a splitter to get digits part of file name
  number = splitter.findall(filename) or ['0']                                      # get number part from filename
  only_name = filename.replace(number[0], '')                                       # get only name from filename removing the number from it
  i = 0
  matching = [s for s in onlyfiles if only_name in s]                               # build array only with files names that match the only_name (from file name)
  if len(matching) == 0:                                                            # if no files matchs the criteria returns the name itself, don't exist any
      return file
  while i < len(matching):                                                          # interates only the array of matching files and extracts the number from it
    number.append((splitter.findall(matching[i]) or [0])[0])                        # add to number array the numbers from file found
    i += 1
  number = [int(i) for i in number]                                                 # converts all number array to int (cast), some of then are strings
  largest_number = max(number)                                                      # get the max value from array
  return '{0}{1}{2}'.format(only_name, str(largest_number + 1), file_extension)     # returns the new file number

filename = 'video.avi'
print(load_file(filename))

out = cv2.VideoWriter(load_file(filename), fourcc, fps, (int(width), int(height)))
```

Comment: e isso em forma de função?? alguma ideia? em que o argumento fosse o nome do output.

Comment: Isso é muito fácil, dá um olhada agora.

Comment: oh sim claro xd, muito obrigado!

Comment: ok, funciona porem pega sempre no video do filename. Depois de ser executado novamente ele pega no video0 outra vez em vez de no video1b (que deveria gerar o video2).
basicamente queria pegar no ULTIMO e incrementar.
alguma ideia?? desculpa lá já agora e obrigado :c

Comment: Precisas de percorrer toda a diretoria e verificar se existe um ficheiro com esse nome, esta função fó verifica se aquele que lhe passas existe.

Comment: e como iria percorrer a diretoria?

Comment: Dá uma olhada, já coloquei essa função com pesquisa, confirma se funciona. Não tenho como testar.

Comment: hmm obrigado, vou testar agora

Comment: ele vai sempre buscar o filename = 'video1.avi', cria o video2.avi, mas depois nunca cria o video3.avi etcc,  substitui o video2.avi

Comment: Já percebi porquê, estava a validar com o if fora do while, tem de ser primeiro o while, percorre toda a diretoria à procura do ficheiro, se encontrar passa para o maximo encontrado para o if e retorna esse máximo + 1. Testa agora.

Comment: continua igual, tambem nao percebo porque, o codigo parece.me estar correto, substitui na mesma o ultimo video gerado (video2.avi)

Comment: quer dizer, agora nem encrementa para o video2, continua modificando o video1, enganei-me no ultimo comentario

Comment: Lol...que erro básico...esqueci do i += 1, ficava sempre no zero....he eh, tenta agora

Comment: só está a alterar o video1 :(  já estou sem fé ahah :c, ja nao entendo nada xd

Comment: Faz debug, tenta perceber o que falta aí.

Comment: sim é o que estou a fazer, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Oi, resolvi. A solução estava um pouco longe. Dá uma olhada agora. Tive de criar um projeto local para testar, ontem não conseguia. Deixei notas no código para poderes perceber o que é feito step by step. Pode não resolver tudo, mas pelo menos existindo um ficheiro video.avi e outro video10.avi, ele vai encontrar o maior e vai retornar video11.avi.

Comment: desde já já obrigado! o que me está a fazer é pegar no video com o numero mais alto (ex: video1), cria um video2(que n funciona) e cria tambem um video3(que é, o que é suposto ser)..
consecutivamente pega no video3, cria um video4 que nao funciona e cria tambem um video5 que é o que é suposto..  mas isto com um bocado de debug deve ir ao sitio hehe

Comment: Agora como consegui testar, parece-me que não estás a fazer qualquer coisa bem. Repara na linha que adicionei ao código, é assim que estás a utilizar, com o nome base, 'video.avi'...se passares assim, parece-me que está ok.

Comment: o problema é que chamo a função duas vezes, mas já percebi o erro, vou já alterar o meu código. obrigado pela ajuda